# How can I add links or color changes to a var string in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, variables

So, I have a site that has a random on-load slideshow with div containers calling text for each slide. I want to be able to add links and/or color changes to specific words. Here's a JSFIDDLE link of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/shadna/Agq7W/

Just for convenience here's the coding:

JS::

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#homebanner').css({backgroundColor: "#000"}); 
    var totalCount = 4; 
    var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );
    var hText = ["WE SPEAK ARCHITECTURE", "WE HAVE HIGH SPIRIT(S)",  "STRATEGY: BUILT ON HUMAN-CENTERED", "FOREVER IN BLUE JEANS"];
    var hsubText = ["CLIENT: EDA ARCHITECTS", "CLIENT: HIGH WEST DISTILLERY", "CLIENT: ARCHITECTURAL NEXUS",  "CLIENT: VAULT DENIM"];

    function setBGImage() { 
        var bgimage = 'http://bwpcommunications.com/TESTING/images/homepage/'+num+'.jpg';
        $('#homebanner').css({
            backgroundImage:"url("+bgimage+")",
        }); 
        $('#htxt').html(hText[num - 1]);
        $('#hsubtxt').html(hsubText[num - 1]);
    } 
    setBGImage(); 
});
```

HTML::

```
<div id="homebanner">
    <div id="hwrap">
        <div id="htxt"></div>
    <div id="hsubtxt"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any information would be helpful to this humble learner of JS.

Comment: You'll find it tough to target specific words in the string unless they're exact matches. Why are you not simply wrapping them in a `span` with an id so you can target them with js?

Comment: Okay, and *which words* did you want to colour, style or make into a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want (only changes posted here)

```
var hsubText = [
    { client : "EDA ARCHITECTS", url : 'http://example.com' },
    { client : "HIGH WEST DISTILLERY",  url : 'http://example.com'},
    { client : "ARCHITECTURAL NEXUS",  url : 'http://example.com' },
    { client : "VAULT DENIM",  url : 'http://example.com' }
];
function setBGImage()
{ 
    var bgimage = 'http://bwpcommunications.com/TESTING/images/homepage/'+num+'.jpg';
    $('#homebanner').css({ 'backgroundImage':'url('+bgimage+')' }); 
    $('#htxt').html(hText[num - 1]);
    var client = hsubText[num - 1].client;
    var url = hsubText[num - 1].url;
    $('#hsubtxt').html('CLIENT : <a href="'+url+'">'+client+'</a>');
 }
```

**CSS:**

```
#hwrap a { color:red }
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Agq7W/5/)

**Updated :** (Since `OP` asked for it in the comment)

```
function setBGImage()
{ 
    var bgimage = 'http://bwpcommunications.com/TESTING/images/homepage/'+num+'.jpg';
    $('#homebanner').css({ 'backgroundImage':'url('+bgimage+')' }); 
    var words = hText[num - 1].split(' ');
    var wordsFirst = words.shift();
    $('#htxt').html($('<span/>', { text:wordsFirst, style:'color:yellow'})).append(' '+ words.join(' '));
    var client = hsubText[num - 1].client;
    var url = hsubText[num - 1].url;
    $('#hsubtxt').html('CLIENT : <a href="'+url+'">'+client+'</a>');
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Agq7W/11/)

Comment: Yeah, that's very similar to what David Thomas wrote. But what if I want to change the color of the first word on each htxt element to say, yellow? How can I do that?

Comment: Color of which text ? There is a `css` also for changing the color.

Comment: the htxt (so the main header text). For example: "STRATEGY: BUILT ON HUMAN-CENTERED RESEARCH" the client would like "STRATEGY:" in yellow.

Comment: @Shadna, [here it's](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Agq7W/11/) and sorry for the delay, i was busy with something else.

Comment: @Shadna, let me know if this what you want, I'll leave now, need to get sleep.

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you! Enjoy your sleep! @sheikhheera

Comment: @Shadna, Welcome dear and good night, oops! morning at all :-)

Comment: I don't want to talk down the accepted answer, it's perfectly fine. But in my opinion this is no good use case for javascript usage. It's backend work done on the frontend with no visible reason why.

Comment: How do I know why, it's what the `OP` asked for. It could be that the `OP` doesn't have the access to the back end.

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand correctly: You want to randomly populate a container with one of your projects?

I'd recommend you to go a much easier way:

Build ALL of the containers without javascript in HTML. Then simply use your random number as an index to make visible only one of the containers, also randomly, but much easier due to much less javascript magic. There is no need for this!

If you provide a class for all banners called `.banner` then you can target them in js like that:

```
$('.banner').eq(yourRandomNumber).css('display', 'block');
```

And all other banners should have `display: none`.

Another thing I noticed in your fiddle: You have many IDs for different elements that basically have the same styles. Rather use a class and define the properties once. Then you provide every element with this class. Example:

```
.banner {
    display:block;
    width:100%; 
    height:290px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:700;
```

}

only the styles that differ need to be in a separate class (I'd recommend you to use as few IDs as possible):

```
.faithologybanner {
    background: url(/TESTING/images/elements/banner_faithology001.jpg) no-repeat center top ; 
}
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the response @Nirazul! I'll update the css. But, I'm not quite clear on the js concept. Let me see if I have this straight:

1. Build all 4 containers with styles and links done in html with the class .banner. Should these be hidden?
2. Use the js string you provided and it will generate rabdomly on page load?

I'll give it a shot in JSFIDDLE and let you know what I come up with. Thanks again!

Comment: Not working @Nirazul... here's how I implemented based off of what I understood from your comment:: http://jsfiddle.net/shadna/Agq7W/7/

Comment: You had errors in the URL you provided in the CSS, everything else worked perfectly fine. [See my updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Agq7W/15/)

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same ID, use classes instead because IDs need to be unique!

Answer (score 1):

First, some simplification, and amended code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#homebanner').css({
        backgroundColor: "#000"
    });

    // put all the information in the same place, in this case an
    // array of objects:
    var details = [{
        head: 'WE SPEAK ARCHITECTURE',
        sub: 'EDA ARCHITECTS',
        link: 'http://example.com/edaarchitects.html'
    }, {
        head: 'WE HAVE HIGH SPIRIT(S)',
        sub: 'HIGH WEST DISTILLARY',
        link: 'http://example.com/highwestdistillary.html'
    }, {
        head: 'STRATEGY: BUILT ON HUMAN-CENTERED',
        sub: 'ARCHITECTURAL NEXUS',
        link: 'http://example.com/architecturalnexus.html'
    }, {
        head: 'FOREVER IN BLUE JEANS',
        sub: 'VAULT DENIM',
        link: 'http://example.com/vault-denim.html'
    }],
        // use the length of the details array to work out the upper bounds
        // of the random number in order to allow for easier updating:
        num = Math.floor(Math.random() * details.length),

        // cache the relevant object for later use:
        item = details[num];

    function setBGImage() {
        // using '(num + 1)' because your images aren't zero-indexed (for some reason):
        var bgimage = 'http://bwpcommunications.com/TESTING/images/homepage/' + (num + 1) + '.jpg';
        $('#homebanner').css({
            backgroundImage: "url(" + bgimage + ")",
        });
        $('#htxt').html(item.head);

        // I've taken 'CLIENT: ' out of the 'sub' since it was in all of them.
        // creating an 'a' element using the 'link' information from the object:
        $('#hsubtxt').html('CLIENT: ' + '<a href="' + item.link + '">' + item.sub + '</a>');
    }
    setBGImage();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Agq7W/2/).

Comment: I'm trying Nirazul's solution but not having much luck. I'll run a JSFIDDLE with your solution and see how that works. Thanks for the detailed info! @davidthomas

Comment: Thanks David! I think this will work and it shows me a few things about JS I wasn't aware of! I do wonder if it's possible to make 'CLIENT:' in bold and leave the link unchanged. Thoughts? Here's how I implemented what you gave me with simplified CSS:: http://jsfiddle.net/shadna/Agq7W/8/

Comment: or the first word of each htxt to a separate color?

Comment: To make the 'client' string bold just wrap it with `<strong></strong>`: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Agq7W/12/). For the first word of each htxt to be a specific colour: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Agq7W/13/).